# CSS - Expand containing DIV

Tags: jquery, css

Simple html page with one DIV called holder, which contains other divs.
https://jsfiddle.net/zk3p1z1h/1/

```
#holder {
    border: 2px solid #000080;
}

#redips-drag {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    display: table;
    border: 2px solid #800000;
}
```

As I drag entries across to the drag & drop zone - how do I expand the DIV holder & redips-drag ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using jquery ui for the dragging/dropping?

Comment: I'm using redips js from here: `http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/example23/`

Comment: @Don'tPanic - tags updated.